# "Такие смешные связи — ой, связи! — тонкие ниточки" - как это сделать понятным с первого захода?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мне очень нравятся такие смешные связи — ой, связи! — тонкие ниточки,
>   которые перекидываются от одних людей к другим.

В значении: *громко сказано - связи; ой, что я говорю - связи!* - и что тогда будет со знаками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы оформила это предложение, используя скобки (экспрессивных вариантов предостаточно):

*...такие смешные связи **(ой, связи! — тонкие ниточки),** которые...*

Или:
*...такие смешные связи **(ой, связи! Тонкие ниточки!),** которые...*

Или:

*...такие смешные связи **(ой, связи, тонкие ниточки!),** которые...*

Или:
*...такие смешные связи **(ой! Связи! — тонкие ниточки!),** которые...*